# Spark from_json - how to handle corrupt records

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an use case where I read data from a table and parse a string column into another one with `from_json()` by specifying the schema:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("FromJsonExample").getOrCreate()

input_df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM input_table")

json_schema = "struct<field1:string, field2:integer>"

output_df = input_df.withColumn("parsed_json", from_json(col("json_column"), json_schema))

output_df.show()
```

I am trying to achieve error handling for this column. In case a record is corrupt i want to leave the column null but i want to have another error column that contains anything that can indicate that my record is corupted so I can filter this record at a later point. After reading the documentation it is kinda unclear what this function supports. It is stated in the documentation that you can configure the "options" as same as the json datasource ("options to control parsing. accepts the same options as the json datasource") but untill trying to use the "PERMISSIVE" mode together with "columnNameOfCorruptRecord" it does not generate a new column in case a record is corupt. Searching didnt end up in many results but as far as I see(altho not tested or confirmed) the Databricks documentation specifies that you can use this setting to generate an error column (https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/from_json.html).

To be clear I am not using Databricks but as far as I see the company is founded by Apache Spark Foundation so my expectations are to use/provide the same tools that you can use everywhere. Also I am interested in this specific use case using "from_json" and not reading the data with "read.json()" and configuring options there since this is not possible on my use case.

The following questions remain:

1. How do you error handle the "from_json" method? Is there another way to create a column if an parsing error happens.
2. Is there a way to drop the malformed records since the "options" for the "from_json() seem to not support the "DROPMALFORMED" configuration. Checking by null column afterwards it is not possible since it can already be null before processing.

Comment: could you share some sample records?

Comment: @samkart you can use any schema or records you want. they are not relevant. the question in matter is how to do the error handling for the from_json. if really needed ill provide an example

Comment: it's always good to provide a basic sample. see [mcve]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sample DataFrame (df_1):

```
+---------------------------+
|json_column                |
+---------------------------+
|{'field1':'A', 'field2':1} |
|{'field1':'B', 'field2':2} |
|{'field1': C, 'field2':'3'}|
+---------------------------+
```

Importing necessary packages:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col, when
```

1. Use `columnNameOfCorruptRecord` option to keep track of error records

```
json_options = {"columnNameOfCorruptRecord":"corrupt_json"}
json_schema = "struct<field1:string, field2:integer, corrupt_json:string>"

df_2 = input_df.withColumn(
    "parsed_json",
    from_json(
        col("json_column"),
        schema = json_schema,
        options = json_options
    )
)
```

[image: Corrupted JSON records]

2. Create a new column `corrupt_json` and drop the corrupt_json feild from `parsed_json`

```
df_3 = df_2 \
    .withColumn("corrupt_json", col("parsed_json.corrupt_json")) \
    .withColumn("parsed_json", col("parsed_json").dropFields("corrupt_json"))
```

3. Update the corrupted records in `parsed_json` with `null` value

```
df_4 = df_3.withColumn("parsed_json", when(col("corrupt_json").isNotNull(), None).otherwise(col("parsed_json")))
```

4. Remove corrupted records

```
df_5 = df_4.filter(col("parsed_json").isNotNull()).drop("parsed_json","corrupt_json")
df_5.show()
```

***Output***

```
+--------------------------+
|json_column               |
+--------------------------+
|{'field1':'A', 'field2':1}|
|{'field1':'B', 'field2':2}|
+--------------------------+
```